# javascript xhr.upload is undefined. Can't track upload progress

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to develop a html-5 uploader with progress bar.
I've accomplished sending and receiving the file, but the progress bar remains.

All the examples uses something like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) { ...
```

When I type this in my browser console it responds with *undefined*

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); alert(xhr.upload);
```

How do I get the hand of the upload object so I can track progress?
I've tested in latest Chrome (v16) and Firefox (v9)

Comment: oops. sry about the formating. my first post here.

Comment: Does the alert work? The console is of course going to print out undefined because the first is a statement that does not return a value and the second is a a function call that does not return a value.

Comment: I would assume it should work since: var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); alert(xhr.send); does work.. anyway binding to the xhr.upload gives the error "xhr.upload is undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to just set the `onprogress` directly.

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt){console.log('progress')};
```

and then do what you were doing.

It should work, just creating a new xhr in the console, upload is there.  Something else is going on in your code.

[image]

Comment: I'm only using console. typing exactly "var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();xhr.upload.onprogress=function(e){console.log(e)}" will give the error "xhr.upload is undefined". What am I missing? Does that exact code give you same error?

Comment: just try xhr.upload after your create the xhr

Comment: Found it to be the dajaxice django module that did something to my xhr object. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work in the chrome console

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener("progress", function(){console.log('progress')});
request.open("POST", "/", true);
request.send(null);
```

Comment: Think I found the error. When I used the console in a different browser-environment (new tab), it worked. I've located the error to be the Dajaxice library for python which apparently destroys some properties of the native xhr object. Thanks for the help, got me thinking... :-)

Comment: I ran into the same problem trying to use the JQuery xhr wrapper.

Comment: Works fine, as expected

Answer (score 1):

Found the error. 
When I used the console in a different browser-environment (new tab), it worked. I've located the error to be the Dajaxice library for python which apparently destroys some properties of the native xhr object. Thanks for the help, got me thinking... :-)

Note2-self: Don't assume the console is "clean" when used for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It's not dajaxice issue itself but problem of XMLHTTMLRequest.js library it uses see correspondent known and unfixed issue https://github.com/ilinsky/xmlhttprequest/issues/12

But it's really a blocker to use Dajax/DajaxIce in HTML5 applications